# Job Applying Bot in Python facing IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, index-error

*Disclaimer: I'm coming back to scripting after more than a decade (and I was a novice to begin with) so apologies if the question is mundane but help is much needed and appreciated.*

I'm trying to modify a python script to log me into a job portal, search job vacancies based on attributes and then apply to said jobs.

Since the portal opens new vacancies on separate tabs, the code is supposed to go to the next tab and test the criteria on the job description

The code snippet is as below:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/'+role+'-jobs-in-'+location+'-'+str(i)+'?ctcFilter='+str(LL)+'to'+str(UL))
    
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)

try:
            test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]')
            if all(word in test.text.lower() for word in Skillset):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/button[2]').click()
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            else:
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
except:
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

However, when I run the script, it just logs me in to the portal and goes to the correct listings page but just stays there. Plus, it pops this error:

```
> line 43, in <module> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
> IndexError: list index out of range
```

Not able to understand what list this is referring to and how to fix this code. Any help is appreciated.

The complete code for those interested:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver as wb
import pandas as pd
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = wb.Chrome("/Users/shashank/Desktop/Naukri Auto Apply/chromedriver")


Skillset = ['Marketing','Communications','Sales']
Skillset = [x.lower() for x in Skillset]
LL = 15       #lower limit of expected CTC
UL = 25       #upper limit of expected CTC
location = 'Bangalore'
location = location.lower().replace(" ","-")
role = 'Marketing Manager'
role = role.lower().replace(" ","-")

driver.get("https://www.naukri.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_Layer"]/div').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input').send_keys("email_address_here")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/input').send_keys("password_here")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div[6]/button').click()

time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div').click()

for i in range(1,6):
    driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/'+role+'-jobs-in-'+location+'-'+str(i)+'?ctcFilter='+str(LL)+'to'+str(UL))
    
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)

try:
            test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]')
            if all(word in test.text.lower() for word in Skillset):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/button[2]').click()
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            else:
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
except:
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Thanks in advance for answering! It will really help with the job search!

Comment: print the value of `driver.window_handles` and `len(driver.window_handles)`. See whether it's >1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No need to switch to another window

   When you are opening the `URL` with that specific details in the `for loop`, the page is getting loaded one by one in the same window. Switch to window when there is a New window tab opened. [Link to Refer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python/)
2. Choose Explicit waits instead of `time.sleep()`. You have refined WebdriverWait but never used it.
3. Try to come up with good locators. Go for Relative Xpath instead of Absolute Xpath.[Link to Refer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_locators.htm)

Not sure what you are trying to do in `try` block. The locators does not highlight any elements in the page.

Refer below code:

```
# Imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= Service("path to chromedriver.exe"))
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.naukri.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

login_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Login']")))
login_btn.click()

email = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//form[@name='login-form']//input[contains(@placeholder,'Email')]")))
email.send_keys("abc@gmail.com")

password = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//form[@name='login-form']//input[contains(@placeholder,'password')]")))
password.send_keys("password")

password.submit()

role = "marketing-manager"
loc = "bangalore"
llimt = "15"
ulimit = "25"
for i in range(1,6):
    driver.get(f"https://www.naukri.com/{role}-jobs-in-{loc}-{i}?ctcFilter={llimt}to{ulimit}")
    time.sleep(2)
    # Update for Chat bot
    try:
        chatbot_close = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='chatbot_Nav']/div")))
        chatbot_close.click()
    except:
        print("Chat bot did not appear")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your response @pmadu and for taking the time out to improve the code.

Comment: @ShashankSharma - If the answer was helpful, accept the same. Please see - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: To answer your question: 
The *try* block is supposed to check whether the JD matches the selection criteria, and then applies if it does. 
Here is the article for your reference: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/automate-your-job-applications-using-python-2c378093b901

Comment: Well, now you know there is no need to switch window, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: your script is currently logging me in without a hitch and going to the correct listings page, but after that it just goes on to the next page and the one after that without applying to any jobs.

I'm okay with not having to search the JD with the specified criteria and only applying based on the "role" and "loc" variable. But how can I frame that in python. I'm not sure as a beginner. if you can help me with that I'd appreciate it greatly. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShashankSharma - `I'm okay with not having to search the JD with the specified criteria and only applying based on the "role" and "loc" variable.` Did you try to do that. With valid locators.

Comment: Literally picked up python 2 days ago (only have a background in C++ and basic HTML from my college days which was more than 14 years ago) so I'll try to keep up with you ;) 

I'm assuming this would involve going to the page and inspecting the elements to find the xpath and then using the click() function. Hope I'm correct? 

I'll try to do that. 

Another issue I'm facing is that this Naukri has a chatbot that keeps popping up as a side frame after every few pages. So I wonder how I can detect that and close it in the script?

Comment: Chat bot may or may not appear. Before trying to apply, close the chat bot. Code is updated for the same.

Comment: Regarding applying, yes you have to perform click operations on those jobs to apply. And the job details is going to open in a new tab and you need to switch to that window to APPLY.

Comment: So would the code snippet look something like this:
after the last line of your code, I can enter the following lines:

  driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath name').click() #to open the first listing
                time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #to go to new tab
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath name').click() #to click on the apply button on the first listing
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.close() #close current tab
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) #go back to main tab

Comment: But can I ask how to loop this until all the listings on a page is done and I can go to the next page. (Sorry for the barrage of questions)

Comment: Thanks so much for updating the code to include the pesky chatbot by the way!

Comment: It would be something like, 1. Get all the jobs in a list. 2. Loop through that list to find the job keywords. 3. If it matches Click on the same. 4.Switch to new tab and click on apply. 5.Close the tab(See if you get any confirmation and use the same to make sure you applied Successfully). 6.Switch to parent Window, continue the loop and check the next jobs in the list. So it will be like `nested for loop` . Getting confirmation that Success in applying, should also be in `try` block because if its not successful, that should not stop the process and continue to apply for other jobs.

Comment: And I am not sure how this answer and conversation is not acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Of course its acceptable!